# Problem with parsing wsdl response at python 3

Tags: python

i have question about wsdl parsing. i have code at python 3:

```
wsdl = "wwww.xxxx"
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    with client.settings(raw_response=True):
        result = client.service.GetSearch(
            KEY1="xx",
            KEY2="xx",
            text="NSIN0013720221",
            address_id=112233,
            delivery_id='000000001'
        )
        res = result["SearchResult"]["PartsList"]["part"]["stocks"]["stock"][0]["price"]
        print(res)

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

response:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://api.rossko.ru/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetSearchResponse><ns1:SearchResult><ns1:success>true</ns1:success><ns1:text>NSIN0013720221</ns1:text><ns1:PartsList><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0013720221</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>555</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>SB-3831</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST155</ns1:id><ns1:price>797</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>1</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0422\u043e\u043b\u044c\u044f\u0442\u0442\u0438 \u0443\u043b. \u041e\u043a\u0442\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 148\u0415</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-10T08:30:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-10T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST391</ns1:id><ns1:price>797</ns1:price><ns1:count>6</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>2</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0421\u0430\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-11T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-11T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>797</ns1:price><ns1:count>3</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks><ns1:crosses><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0019660853</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>CTR</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>CBT-84</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST391</ns1:id><ns1:price>755</ns1:price><ns1:count>1</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>2</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0421\u0430\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-11T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-11T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>755</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0023090769</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>LYNXauto</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>C1242LR</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST155</ns1:id><ns1:price>538</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>1</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0422\u043e\u043b\u044c\u044f\u0442\u0442\u0438 \u0443\u043b. \u041e\u043a\u0442\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 148\u0415</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-10T08:30:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-10T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST391</ns1:id><ns1:price>538</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>2</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0421\u0430\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-11T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-11T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>538</ns1:price><ns1:count>134</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST834</ns1:id><ns1:price>538</ns1:price><ns1:count>100</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0004470436</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Toyota</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>48630-59025</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u0420\u044b\u0447\u0430\u0433 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0432\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST68184144</ns1:id><ns1:price>17441.98</ns1:price><ns1:count>1</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSII0007236631</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Hanse</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>hb820121</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST488</ns1:id><ns1:price>449.64</ns1:price><ns1:count>3</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST767</ns1:id><ns1:price>408.76</ns1:price><ns1:count>1</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>6</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-15T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-15T12:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST821</ns1:id><ns1:price>418.05</ns1:price><ns1:count>14</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0019687262</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Masuma</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>MB-3831</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST462</ns1:id><ns1:price>606.64</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>2</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-11T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-11T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST796</ns1:id><ns1:price>605.71</ns1:price><ns1:count>19</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST51059487</ns1:id><ns1:price>606.64</ns1:price><ns1:count>10</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0019671188</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Febest</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>0120-065</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u0432\u0435\u0440\u0445\u043d\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0440\u044b\u0447\u0430\u0433\u0430 | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>393</ns1:price><ns1:count>5</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0006141588</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>CTR</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>CBT-48</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST155</ns1:id><ns1:price>685</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>1</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0422\u043e\u043b\u044c\u044f\u0442\u0442\u0438 \u0443\u043b. \u041e\u043a\u0442\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 148\u0415</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-10T08:30:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-10T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>685</ns1:price><ns1:count>43</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0018564310</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>CTR</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>CBT-77</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>721</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0006395195</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Nipparts</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>J4 882 009</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST74718991</ns1:id><ns1:price>519.31</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST51059487</ns1:id><ns1:price>456.14</ns1:price><ns1:count>1</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST76</ns1:id><ns1:price>565.76</ns1:price><ns1:count>8</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0001092493</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Optimal</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>G3-868</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>831</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0020862611</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>TRW</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>JBJ 553</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST53</ns1:id><ns1:price>1256.01</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST46551689</ns1:id><ns1:price>1471.54</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSII0007961327</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>Asva</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>0120-065</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f | \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432/\u043b\u0435\u0432 |</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST391</ns1:id><ns1:price>328</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>2</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u0421\u0430\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-11T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-11T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST27</ns1:id><ns1:price>328</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>3</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-12T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-12T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSII0015439859</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>GMB</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>01010330</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u041e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0448\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST51059487</ns1:id><ns1:price>552.76</ns1:price><ns1:count>30</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST44380638</ns1:id><ns1:price>551.83</ns1:price><ns1:count>4</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>6</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-15T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-15T12:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST821</ns1:id><ns1:price>570.41</ns1:price><ns1:count>333</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>5</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-14T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-14T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0020286210</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0443\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043d</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>1-06-251</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u0421\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a \u0440\u044b\u0447\u0430\u0433\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0432\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST38608306</ns1:id><ns1:price>764.57</ns1:price><ns1:count>2</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part><ns1:Part><ns1:guid>NSIN0020286211</ns1:guid><ns1:brand>\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0443\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043d</ns1:brand><ns1:partnumber>1-06-2511</ns1:partnumber><ns1:name>\u0421\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a \u0440\u044b\u0447\u0430\u0433\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0432\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438 \u0432\u0435\u0440\u0445\u043d\u0438\u0439</ns1:name><ns1:stocks><ns1:stock><ns1:id>HST38608306</ns1:id><ns1:price>744.13</ns1:price><ns1:count>9</ns1:count><ns1:multiplicity>1</ns1:multiplicity><ns1:type>0</ns1:type><ns1:delivery>4</ns1:delivery><ns1:extra>0</ns1:extra><ns1:description>\u041f\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434</ns1:description><ns1:deliveryStart>2020-08-13T09:40:00</ns1:deliveryStart><ns1:deliveryEnd>2020-08-13T17:00:00</ns1:deliveryEnd></ns1:stock></ns1:stocks></ns1:Part></ns1:crosses></ns1:Part></ns1:PartsList></ns1:SearchResult></ns1:GetSearchResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n"content-type: text/json
```

I get error: and get error: TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable. why i can get value of price? Whats my mistake?

Comment: `result` seems to be an instance of some class called `Response` which does not support that you use the `[]` syntax with it.

Comment: whats my truth way to resolve it?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what `Response` is, because I don't know what `zeep` is and how it works.